# Target api 21 is not listed in eclipse(While creating new project) even after updating my SDK to Lollipop

Tags: android, sdk

I have updated my `SDK` to `Android Lollipop`. I am able to See `Target API 21` in `Android SDK Manager when I access it from the directory where it is saved` however when I create a new project in `Eclipse` it does not show Target `API 21`. Neither it Runs `Emulator` Created for `API 21`. I am done with restating my `eclipse` many times. Any one having any idea what could be wrong??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, my android sdk manager is not showing new API,
**1.** Solution Just click on the following icon Android SDK Manager. It will show all the packages.
[image]

**2.** Open SDK Manager click tools in the top menu -> options and turn on "forse h ttps://...sources"